# Obtaining the Average from a Set of Data XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a table (created using the XSL document supplied below). I need to obtain the average data for each months temperature(min & max) and rainfall.

I have started this but I've made a mess of the template and was wondering if someone can have a look? I'm getting a heap of repeated captions that I don't think should be there and I'm not having any luck pulling the data together yet.

XSL Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    Document   : weather.xsl
    Created on : September 30, 2015, 5:37 PM
    Author     : rory
    Description:
        Purpose of transformation follows.
-->

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:variable name="year" select="2015"/>
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="//measurement[@year=$year]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="monthsOfYear" select="$x[@day=1]/month"/>
    <xsl:variable name="daysOfMonth" select="$x[@month=1]/day"/>
    <xsl:variable name="highestRainfall" select="$x/rainfall[.!=''][not( . &lt; $x/rainfall)]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="highestMinTemp" select="$x/temperature[@type='minimum' and .!=''][not( . &lt; $x/temperature[@type='minimum'])]" />
    <xsl:variable name="lowestMinTemp" select="$x/temperature[@type='minimum' and .!=''][not( $x/temperature[@type='minimum']  &lt; . )]" />
    <xsl:variable name="highestMaxTemp" select="$x/temperature[@type='maximum' and .!=''][not( . &lt; $x/temperature[@type='maximum'])]" />
    <xsl:variable name="lowestMaxTemp" select="$x/temperature[@type='maximum' and .!=''][not( $x/temperature[@type='maximum']  &lt; . )]" />
    <xsl:variable name="highestSolar" select="$x/solar[.!=''][not( . &lt; $x/solar)]"/>

    <!-- TODO customize transformation rules 
         syntax recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt 
    -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Formatted Weather Outputs (Question 6)</title>

                <style>
                    .odd{
                        background: lightgreen;
                    }
                    .even{
                        background: violet;
                    }
                    .negative{
                        color: red;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="1" style="text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="weather" />
                </table>
                <table border="1" style="text-align:center;border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="weather/measurement[@year='2015']" />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="weather">
        <caption>Daily Observations</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Date (DD/MM/YYYY)</th>
                <th>Min Temp (<sup>o</sup>C)</th>
                <th>Max Temp (<sup>o</sup>C)</th>
                <th>Solar Radiation (kwh/m<sup>2</sup>)</th>
                <th>Rainfall (mm)</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- Only display dates for 2015 -->
            <xsl:for-each select="measurement[@year='2015']">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="(@month mod 2 != 0)">odd</xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>even</xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:attribute>

                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(@day, '/', @month, '/', @year)" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="temperature[@type='minimum'] &lt; 0">negative</xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:if test=" temperature[@type='minimum'] = $highestMinTemp">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:gold</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test=" temperature[@type='minimum'] = $lowestMinTemp">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:lightblue</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="temperature[@type='minimum']" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:if test=" temperature[@type='maximum'] = $highestMaxTemp">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:gold</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test=" temperature[@type='maximum'] = $lowestMaxTemp">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:lightblue</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>    
                        <xsl:value-of select="temperature[@type='maximum']" />                                   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:if test=" solar = $highestSolar">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:gold</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="solar"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:if test=" rainfall = $highestRainfall">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:gold</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="rainfall" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="weather/measurement">
        <xsl:variable name="totalMinTemp" select="sum(temperature[@type='minimum'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="numberOfDays" select="count(temperature[@type='minimum'])" />
        <xsl:variable name="averageMinTemp" select="($totalMinTemp div $numberOfDays)" />
        <xsl:variable name="month" select="@month" />
        <caption>Monthly Averages</caption>
            <tr><td colspan="4">Average</td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Month</td><td>Min Temp<sup>o</sup>C</td><td>Max Temp<sup>o</sup>C</td><td>Solar radiation kwh/m<sup>2</sup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><!--<xsl:value-of select="$month" />-->T</td>
            </tr>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input document sample:

```
<weather>
    <measurement year="2015" month="09" day="19">
        <rainfall>0.0</rainfall>
        <temperature type="minimum">5.2</temperature>
        <temperature type="maximum">19.9</temperature>
        <solar>5.0</solar>
    </measurement>
    <measurement year="2015" month="09" day="20">
        <rainfall>0.0</rainfall>
        <temperature type="minimum">5.3</temperature>
        <temperature type="maximum">22.7</temperature>
        <solar>5.3</solar>
    </measurement>
    <measurement year="2015" month="09" day="21">
        <rainfall>0.0</rainfall>
        <temperature type="minimum">6.9</temperature>
        <temperature type="maximum">17.6</temperature>
        <solar>3.8</solar>
    </measurement>
</weather>
```

Comment: Can you add an example input and desired output?

Comment: I suspect this is a grouping problem: my guess is that you have a number of measurement elements and you want to group them by month. Can't possibly attempt a solution based on guessing what the source document looks like, given only a non-working stylesheet to work from.

Comment: Note also that grouping problems are much easier in XSLT 2.0, so you really need to tell us whether you have access to an XSLT 2.0 processor.

Comment: @DanielHaley have added the input document sample.

Comment: @MichaelKay have added an input sample.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
<xsl:template match="weather/measurement">
        <xsl:variable name="totalMinTemp" select="sum(temperature[@type='minimum'])" />
```

You are processing one measurement, and it only has one temperature with @type=minimum, so the sum of a singleton set is trivially that value. I suspect you want to sum over all the measurements for a month or a year, and you can't do that when you are processing an individual measurement.

If you can use XSLT 2.0, you'll want to write something like

```
<xsl:template match="weather">
  ...
  <xsl:for-each-group select="measurement[@year='2015']" group-by="@month">
    <xsl:variable name="totalMinTemp" select="sum(current-group()/temperature[@type='minimum'])" />
    <xsl:variable name="numberOfDays" select="count(current-group()/temperature[@type='minimum'])" />
     ....
```

As I mentioned earlier, grouping in XSLT 1.0 is more tricky: you'll need to read up on "Muenchian grouping" which is covered in most good XSLT textbooks, and there are also plenty of online resources.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your advice there. How does having two "weather" templates affect what I'm going to do? Is there some way it can decide which should be overloading? Thanks Rory

Comment: I added the match="weather" line purely to indicate that this code expects to execute with the "weather" element as the context node. You can integrate it with your other code any way you like, e.g. it could go in your existing match="weather" template or in a named template called from there.